# Lambda error has no meaningful message in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Im trying to configure Lambda with API Gateway. When hitting my endpoint I see:

```
{
    message: "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Then I would like to see what error so I go to Cloudwatch. And I see it under Log events. But it does not give me any information, only:

> 2021-12-09T10:17:12.628+01:00
>
> START RequestId: 4e8f5439-1054-4234e-a6b8-a5ccdbd242342 Version:
> $LATEST

How can I get a useful error message?

#### the Lambda

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: {msg:'Hello from Lambda!'},
    };
};
```

Comment: If it matters, I suspect I am missing something on roles/authorization.

Comment: How does your lambda look like? Are you handling and printing the errors? I suspect not

Comment: Updated question with the lambda function @Paolo

Comment: Do you only have one cloudwatch log? Or do you have one `START`, one `END`, and one `REPORT` ?

Comment: Yes, I see START, END and REPORT as separate log events but none of them contain any message. Also, if this is an auth issue the code would never execute so I cant print/log from the JS code?

Comment: Exactly, I don't think the lambda function is being invoked at all; you're probably looking at some previous log. I imagine the error code you are getting from API gateway is code 500? It sounds like you haven't configured the API gateway with the necessary permissions to invoke the lambda altogether https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-lambda-stage-variable-500/